# Is this behaviour of SETI expected?

Tags: kittens-game

I've found a bug, I think. I've been playing kittens after setting priceRatio on all buildings and structures (religious, ziggurat and "normal") and I've realised after a while that although I have 500 Ivory Towers and 500 Sky Palaces and 500 Ivory Citadels I'm not getting any events related to them. No Ivory Meteors, no Unicor Rifts, no Alicorns. This happens because I also had 500 observatories. 500 observatories give me "chance" (in onNewDay() function) equal to 10025. This means that there is an astronomical event everyday. In code after check for chance being greater than random number some stuff with handlers and timeouts follows, and then it comes:

```
        //---------------- SETI hack-------------------
        if (this.game.workshop.get("seti").researched){
            this.observeHandler();
            return;
        }
```

Note "return". This means that if there is an astronomical event, there is no chance for meteors giving minerals, alicorns, unicorn rifts and so on. This also means that if someone were able to build enough observatories in IronWill mode, s/he could build a hut (and exit Iron Will mode) and no zebra hunter will leave. Yeah, I know, 500 observatories in Iron Will.

Anyway, I think that this is a bug.

Comment: Also - with enough pastures demand for catnip starts to be greater than zero, which means that one can generate catnip simply by having a lot of kittens. Not that it's an error, but I think that it shouldn't be like this. Not to mention that faith multiplier, carried over from reset to reset, doesn't seem to have diminishing returns. It's not a real problem, since I've been playing under unusual conditions, but it's still something that could be changed to increase robustness.

Comment: `with enough pastures demand for catnip starts to be greater than zero`

It starts to give diminishing return up from 75%

`Not to mention that faith multiplier, carried over from reset to reset, doesn't seem to have diminishing returns`

Both faith multiplier and faith production bonuses have diminishing return.

Comment: I just checked it - I entered in the console:

gamePage.bld.get('pasture').val = 3500;
gamePage.bld.get('field').val = 0;

and I've removed all farmers, and my catnip production is at 10k and catnip tooltip shows only: "Demand: +10.519k" so maybe it's worth looking into.

You know, I'm not saying it was aliens, but it was aliens.

Comment: Also note, that I couldn't find any signs of deminishing results in code updating and changing effects. Not that I know this code very well. I've been checking version 1.0.2.2.

Comment: Search the code base for `getHyperbolicEffect`. It definitely works with Tradeposts, your Fur/Ivory demand never goes positive. It only  works for calls to `getEffect` which have negative values AND pass in a second argument. I believe you are correct about the original post, probably a bug.

Comment: @bloodrizer: It looks to me like the `useHypHack` in `game.js` is actually turning off diminishing returns for catnip demand reduction. I don't think it's currently feasible to hit 75% catnip demand reduction, but if it happens, that code might need fixing.

Comment: Heh, I see that I wrote "astrological events". Twice. Damn. Thanks for edit. And to thing that my girlfriend's dad is an astronomer and she told me quite a few times about endless jokes in primary school that her dad is an astrologer... I should be more careful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, this is a bug, thanks for spotting this.
Fixed it in 1.0.3.2

Answer (score -1):

Having SETI researched will silence all astronomical log entries.  They still happen, you just aren't notified.

Comment: This isn't about the astronomical events. This is about meteors, unicorn rifts, ivory meteors, and alicorns. SETI isn't supposed to do anything to those.